# Existence of a spin structure in Kaehlerian manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, kahler-manifolds, spin-geometry

I have a few questions regarding the existence of a spin structure on Kaehlerian and hyperKaehlerian manifolds. I cannot seem to provide a reference for proofs or counterexamples, so references are more than welcome.

> *Q1:* Does every hyperKaehler manifold admit a spin structure?
>
> *Q2:* Does every Kaehler manifold admit a spin structure?
>
> *Q3:* Are there any dimension constraints on the existence of a spin structure on such manifolds?

*Remark:* According to page 85 of Jost's *Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis* (6th edition), every orientable Riemannian manifold in dimension 4 carries a spin$^c$ structure. Since complex manifolds are orientable, this offers a partial to answer to the above questions. Jost, however, provides no proof or reference.

Comment: Sadly, my library has been depleted, so I no longer have Lawson/Michelsohn's beautiful book *Spin Geometry*, but that's the standard reference for all such questions.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you very much for the reference :)

Comment: I don't know about hyperKaehler. For Kaehler note that $\mathbb{C}P(n)$ admits a Kaehler structure but for even $n$ is not spin.  Its non-spinability can be proven by showing its second Stiefel-Whitney classes are non-zero (see Milnor and Stasheff).  For $n$ odd that class is zero and so those complex projective spaces are spin.

Comment: Apparently all hyperKaehler manifolds are Calabi-Yau's and all CYs are spin.  I do not understand the proof of either of those facts yet, I just pieced that together from the [hyperKaehler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperk%C3%A4hler_manifold) and [spin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_structure) Wikipedia pages.  I will try to understand those facts and turn this into an answer at some point.

Comment: If you can confirm my reasoning in (this question)[https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3318145/is-sun-subset-textspin2n] for me then I can give an explanation of why hyperKaehlers are spin.

Answer (score 1):

A1: Yes, a hyperKähler manifold is spin.  If we take our definition of a hyperKähler manifold to be a $4k$-manifold with holonomy group contained in the symplectic group $Sp(k)$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperk%C3%A4hler_manifold)) and we take our definition of a spin-manifold to be an $n$-manifold $M$ with a reduction of the frame bundle $Fr(TM)$ to $Spin(n)$.

We have the containments $Sp(k) \subset SU(2k) \subset Spin(4k)$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_group#Sp(n)) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3318145/is-sun-subset-textspin2n]) ).  Therefore the reduction of the holonomy group of a $4k$-manifold to $Sp(k)$ is more than sufficient to reduce $Fr(TM)$ to $Spin(4k)$.  Hence these are spin.

A2: No, a Kähler manifold need not be spin.  [Complex projective space is Kähler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4hler_manifold#Examples), but $\mathbb{C}P(2n)$ is not spin, as can be proven by computing that its second Stiefel-Whitney class is non-zero (see Milnor and Stasheff).  I do not know if there are any nice results like "Kähler + ______ $\implies$ spin."  It is worth pointing out that the $\mathbb{C}P(2n+1)$'s are spin (same reference).

I don't know anything about Q3.