# Embedd SU(n) into an enlarged twisted Spin(2n) in terms of Lie groups precisely

Tags: representation-theory, manifolds, lie-groups, quotient-spaces, homogeneous-spaces

It is standard practice to show
$$
SU(n) \subset SO(2n).
$$

However, some post [Is $SU(n) \subset \text{Spin}(2n)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3318145/141334) suggests that $\DeclareMathOperator\Spin{Spin}$
$$
SU(n) \subset \Spin(2n) (?).
$$

I am very puzzled, because $1 \to \mathbb{Z}/2 \to \Spin(2n)\to SO(2n) \to 1$, so $SO(2n)  \not  \subset  \Spin(2n) $. The $ SO(2n) $ is only a quotient group not a normal subgroup.

- Is this answer $SU(n) \subset \Spin(2n)$ true of false, [Is $SU(n) \subset \text{Spin}(2n)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3318145/141334)? I thought $SU(n) \not\subset \Spin(2n)$
- However, is it possible to show that
  $$
  SU(n) \times U(1) \subset \frac{\Spin(2n) \times \Spin(2)}{\mathbb{Z}/2}=  \frac{\Spin(2n) \times U(1)}{\mathbb{Z}/2}?
  $$

$$
SU(n) \times SU(2) \subset  \frac{\Spin(2n) \times \Spin(3)}{\mathbb{Z}/2}=\frac{\Spin(2n) \times SU(2)}{\mathbb{Z}/2}?
$$
precisely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $SU(n)$ is simply connected, any map $SU(n)\rightarrow SO(k)$ lifts to a map $SU(n)\rightarrow Spin(k)$.  Further, there is a unique lift mapping the identity in $SU(n)$ to the identity in $Spin(k)$.

Apply this to the inclusion map $i:SU(n)\rightarrow SO(2n)$.  Note that $i$ is injective, so any lift must also be injective, so there are always copies of $SU(n)$ in $Spin(2n)$

Comment: Thanks voted up. I am puzzled, because 1→ℤ/2→(2)→(2)→1, so (2)⊄(2). The (2) is only a quotient group not a normal subgroup. Would this be a problem?

Comment: I don't see why it would be a problem.  Suppose you replace $SU(n)$ with the trivial group.  Would you say your exact sequences are ab problem in that case?

Comment: Before accept your answer, thanks I have a naive puzzle as bove, do you think that $\frac{Spin(n) \times Spin(10)}{\mathbb{Z}_2}$ contains $Spin(n) \times SU(5)$?

Comment: p.s. Your answer only says ${Spin(n) \times Spin(10)}$ contains $Spin(n) \times SU(5)$.

Comment: (2) what is the value of $k$?

Comment: may you know this math.stackexchange.com/q/3607058/141334 too ?

Comment: For (1), it may depend on which $\mathbb{Z}_2$ your referring to.  For (2), $k$ is arbitrary, but for your application, it is $2n$.

Comment: For (1), I am wondering the common ℤ/2. Would that ()×(10)ℤ2 contain ()×(5)?

Comment: accepted, can you comment on this: math.stackexchange.com/q/3607058/141334 ? I believe it is true but I cannot show it in general...